# Constraint on Labels in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

In Neo4j, I want to create a data model for celestial bodies.

I created the following node labels:

```
CelestialBody
Sun
Planet
Moon
```

(I didn't add `MoonMoons` because it's still to be proved and observed :p )

Then I created the `ORBITS` relationship type.

So, I have paths like:

```
(:Moon:CelestialBody)-[:ORBITS]->(:Planet:CelestialBody)-[:ORBITS]->(:Sun:CelestialBody)
```

But when I want to visualize the schema, I see the `:ORBITS` relationship between the four labels because they all have the `CelestialBody` label.

I would like to enforce an `ORBITS` constraint to reject reverted or transitive relationships like:

```
(:Moon)-[:ORBITS]->(:Sun)
(:Planet)-[r:ORBITS]->(:Moon)
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in way to constrain relationship types between node labels.

However, you can create your own APOC [trigger](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/background-operations/triggers/) to validate `ORBITS` relationship creations (at the cost of additional overhead for all relationship creations).

Something like this may work for you:

```
CALL apoc.trigger.add(
  "constrainORBITS",
  "UNWIND $createdRelationships AS rel
   WITH rel
   WHERE TYPE(rel) = 'ORBITS'
   WITH rel, LABELS(STARTNODE(rel)) AS a, LABELS(ENDNODE(rel)) AS b
   CALL apoc.util.validate(
     ('Moon' IN a AND NOT 'Planet' IN b) OR
     ('Planet' IN a AND NOT 'Sun' IN b) OR
     'Sun' IN a,
     'ORBITS relationship (%d) violated constraint. Start node labels: %s, End node labels: %s',
     [ID(rel), a, b])
   RETURN null",
  {phase:'before'})
```

A violation of this custom "constraint" should cause a `Neo.ClientError.Transaction.TransactionHookFailed` exception to be thrown.

Comment: Hi thank you for this precise answer. I'll try this and evaluate the overhead.